# Changing spotlight direction in Processing

Tags: java, glsl, processing, shader

I'm trying to implement 2 spotlights at the top of the scene using `Processing` that changes their respective directions overtime. I tried using the default `spotlight(r,g,b,x,y,z,nx,ny,nz,angle,concentration)` method to create the spotlights and tried changing the `nx`, `ny` and `nz` variables to change the light direction. However, the method don't seem to take in the 3 variables. This is the glsl that I'm using.

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 normalInterp;
varying vec3 vertPos;



uniform int lightCount;
uniform vec4 lightPosition[8];
uniform vec3 lightNormal[8];


//ambient
const vec3 ambientColor = vec3(0.1, 0, 0);
//diffuse
const vec3 diffuseColor = vec3(0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
//specular
const vec3 specColor = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
//specular reflection parameter
const float n = 30.0;
//Depth cueing
//not implemented

void main() {

  float lightR = 0.0;
  float lightG = 0.0;
  float lightB = 0.0;

  for (int i = 0; i < lightCount; i++)
  {
   vec3 normal = normalize(normalInterp);
   vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPosition[i] - vertPos);

   //diffuse
   float diffuse = max(dot(lightDir,normal), 0.0);

   //specular
   float specular = 0.0;
   if(diffuse > 0.0) {
      vec3 viewDir = normalize(-vertPos);
      vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
      float specAngle = max(dot(reflectDir, viewDir), 0.0);
      specular = pow(specAngle, n);
  }

  //Note: can add in depth cueing here
  vec3 colorLinear = ambientColor +
                     diffuse * diffuseColor +
                     specular * specColor;

  lightR += colorLinear.x;
  lightG += colorLinear.y;
  lightB += colorLinear.z;

  }

  gl_FragColor = vec4(lightR,lightG,lightB, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: What is the state of the question? Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

There is an simple issue in the shader program. First there is a typo. It has to be `lightPosition` rather than `lightPostion`. But that is not the only issue.

The type of `lightPosition[i]` is `vec4` and the typo of `vertPos` is `vec3`. That causes and error when `vertPos` is subtracted from `lightPosition[i]`.

Either you have to construct a `vec3` from `lightPosition[i]`:

<s>`vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPostion[i] - vertPos);`</s>

```c
vec3 lightDir = normalize(vec3(lightPosition[i]) - vertPos);
```

Or You have to get the x, y and z component form `lightPosition[i]` (see [Swizzling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Swizzling)):

```c
vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPosition[i].xyz - vertPos);
```

Both solutions lead to the same result.

---

Of course, the light position has to be set relative to the object. Note when [`spotLight()`](https://processing.org/reference/spotLight_.html) is called, the the light position and direction is transformed by the current model view matrix.

See the example:

[image]

Vertex shader

```c
uniform mat4 modelview;
uniform mat4 transform;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 color;
attribute vec3 normal;

varying vec3 normalInterp;
varying vec3 vertPos;

varying vec4 vertColor;

void main() {
    gl_Position = transform * position;
    vertPos = vec3(modelview * position);
    normalInterp = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
}
```

Fragment shader

```c
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 normalInterp;
varying vec3 vertPos;

uniform int lightCount;
uniform vec4 lightPosition[8];
uniform vec3 lightNormal[8];
uniform vec3 lightDiffuse[8];
uniform vec3 lightSpecular[8];
uniform vec2 lightSpot[8];

const vec3 ambientColor = vec3(0.2);
const vec3 diffuseColor = vec3(1.0);
const vec3 specColor = vec3(1.0);
const float n = 30.0;

void main() {

    vec3 lightColor = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < lightCount; i++)
    {
        // ambient
        lightColor += lightDiffuse[i] * ambientColor;

        vec3 normal = normalize(normalInterp);
        vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPosition[i].xyz - vertPos);

        float spot = dot(-lightNormal[i], lightDir);
        if (spot < lightSpot[i].x)
            continue;

        //diffuse
        float diffuse = max(dot(lightDir,normal), 0.0);
        lightColor += diffuse * lightDiffuse[i] * diffuseColor;

        //specular
        if(diffuse > 0.0) {
            vec3 viewDir = normalize(-vertPos);
            vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
            float specAngle = max(dot(reflectDir, viewDir), 0.0);
            float specular = pow(specAngle, n);
            lightColor += specular * lightSpecular[i] * specColor;
        }
    }

    gl_FragColor = vec4(lightColor.rgb, 1.0);
}
```

Code

```java
PShader lightShader;

void setup() {
    size(800, 600, P3D);
    lightShader = loadShader("fragment.glsl","vertex.glsl");
}

float ry = 0.0;
void draw() {
    background(0);

    shader(lightShader);

    translate(width/2.0, height/2.0);

    spotLight(255, 0, 0, 0, 500, 500, 0, -1, -1, PI/25, 2);
    spotLight(0, 0, 255, 500, 0, 500, -1, 0, -1, PI/25, 2);

    rotateY(ry);
    rotateX(-0.5);
    ry += 0.02;

    noStroke();
    box(200);
}
```

Comment: Sorry. it was supposed to be lightPosition instead. the i got left out when i copied the code over. This still doesn't solve the issue of the glsl being unable to take in the nx, ny and nz variable for the spotlight(r, g, b, x, y, z, nx , ny, nz, angle, concentration).

Comment: @KelonEe What do you expect? `lightNormal` is never used in your shader program.

Comment: yea. i tried using lightnormal in, but it still does not change the light direction..